# wordpress post_exists() always fails with post titles containing '&'

Tags: wordpress, title

I have a script that auto-creates posts from data provided, the main check that it does before creating a new post is to see if any post already exists with the title provided

`$post_id = post_exists($title, '', '', 'cpt');`

The problem is it fails with any post containing '&'. I have the incoming title wrapped in `html_entity_decode` before I pass it to `wp_insert_post()`, and even before formatting it with this, all of the incoming titles are using the '&' character and not any html entity or other format.

When I check in the wordpress database, the titles are also saved with the '&' symbol. But for some reason, the post_exists() check fails on all of them.

I'm kind of at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I've basically admitted defeat, I'm now just running str_replace('&', 'and', $title) on all my titles and that has resolved the issue.